# filtering on multi source grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik mvc grid which its data comes from two different source.

Assume I have a model like this :

```
    public class Customer
    {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public Guid CreatorUserId {get;set;}
       public string CreatorUsername 
       {
            get
            {
                return System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(CreatorUserId).UserName;
            }
       }
}
```

I save the customer info in a table like **Customer(Id,Name,CreatorUserId)** ,and then the CreatorFullname comes from membership provider (which connected to Active Directory).

If I bind the above model to a Telerik grid (with ajax enabled option) , everything is ok (paging,ajax-paging,...). Also sorting on  CreatorUsername  works (although it is not correct) but the main problem is about filtering. It fails because the CreatorUsername is not part of Customer table in main source.

How to overcome this? (specially when I use Telerik-MVC grid)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement a foreign-key column such as the one in [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn)? As you can see in the demo, the EmployeeID column is not from the same table as the other columns, yet you can filter the Grid perfectly fine through it.

Comment: As I told the needed column is not in the same Database. It is in Active Directory

Comment: Even if it's not from the same database all you would need to do is to have an object that includes the AD information as a field, or provide the Grid with an IEnumerable of these AD fields that you're looking for. Additionally you could look into utilizing a pattern which will allow you to provide an additional layer between the Grid and your data, granting you the ability to update this layer before committing back to your DB.

Comment: Carl, the problem is not in showing or updating data. The problem happens when I want to use column filtering (which is done automatically by telerik grid and I have no any control over it). It raises an error on "CreatorUsername" filtering and it is becuase of converting and merging the column in the sql query. I need a solution to let me having more control on filtering/ordering senario s on telerik MVC grid.